# Ruby - array difference method which takes position into account

Tags: arrays, ruby, set

I'm trying to find the number of changed words between two sentences, by converting the sentences to arrays of words.  I can't use the standard `Array#-` method, because that removes instances of the same value wherever it appears, but I want to keep those instances in the results.

To illustrate using arrays of numbers:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
arr2 - arr1
=> [] #I want [4, 1, 2, 4]

#another example: simple reordering.  

arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr4 = [4, 3, 2, 1]
arr4 - arr3
=> [] #I want [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

It's not as simple as just iterating through and seeing if `arr1[i]` is equal to `arr2[i]` for every value of `i` - if I did that, then in the first example it would return the whole of arr2, because the addition of the 4 at the start has pushed every value onto a new index.

What I need to do, I think, is something along the lines of 'get every **set** of values in arr1 and try removing that **set* of values from arr2, then at the end I should be left with all of the new sets of values (ie phrases) in arr2, and that's what I'm going to count as the number of words in the edit.  But, it wouldn't be every set, since that would include lots of two-value sets, it's more like "look for the longest sets you can remove".

Does anyone know if there's a relatively straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Seems to be a variation of the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Comment: So the second example returns what it does because the values in `arr4` are not in the same order as those in `arr3`?

Comment: @Chris Yes that's right.  I'm trying to identify "novel chunks" of the second array, if you like.

Comment: @Stefan I wondered if this was one of those classic computer science problems.  That page you linked to gave me a nice idea of writing out the arrays  as files and diffing them.

Comment: While @Stefan is correct, there are some approaches you can take that don't require word-wise diffs or set-based comparisons. I have provided six options below, each of which is admittedly naive in the sense that it solves for a given data set and group of assumptions without being exhaustive in its approach to correctness, but at least one of which should address your two defined use cases. If you find a better solution, don't be afraid to post it as a self-answer; that may help others with similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the elements in the first array, we immediately return the second array if the item is not found in a clone of the second. This short-circuits the rest of the method, of course.

If it *is* we push all proceeding elements onto a result using `#shift` to remove them from `temp` so they're not considered on the next iteration. We shift again to remove the item we were searching for. At the end we append whatever's left of temp and flatten the array.

```
def solve(arr1, arr2)
  temp = arr2.clone

  arr1.each_with_object([]) do |x, r|
    pos = temp.find_index(x)
    return arr2 unless pos
    r.concat(temp.shift(pos))
    temp.shift
  end + temp
end
```

Now:

```rb
solve(arr1, arr2)
# => [4, 1, 2, 4]

solve(arr3, arr4)
# => [4, 3, 2, 1]

solve("hello world wooble".split, "hello foo world bar baz wooble".split)
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

solve("hello world wooble".split, "hello foo world bar baz".split)
# => ["hello", "foo", "world", "bar", "baz"]
```

Comment: thanks - with the last example i'd expect it to return `["foo",  "bar", "baz"]` because (intuitively speaking at least) the edit consisted of adding those words (as well as removing 'wooble' - which has made me realise that my intended behaviour doesn't care about removed words at all, which may or may not be appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

After reading it through the question again, and looking at the comments, you're looking to remove a range from an array if it matches another array? (I'm certain that there are possible optimisations)

Code:

```
class Array
  def minus(other)
    found=-1
    (0..(self.length-other.length)).each do |x|
      if self[x,other.length] == other
        found = x
        break
      end
    end
    if found >= 0
      self[0, found] + self[found+other.length,self.length]
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

examples of output:

```
# array minus itself
2.7.2 :263 > arr2.minus arr2
 => []

# your arrays
2.7.2 :264 > arr2.minus arr1
 => [4, 1, 2, 4]

2.7.2 :265 > arr4.minus arr3
 => [4, 3, 2, 1]

# an array with repeated elements
2.7.2 :275 > arr6 = [1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
 => [1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
2.7.2 :276 > arr5 = [4, 2, 4]
 => [4, 2, 4]

2.7.2 :277 > arr6.minus arr5
 => [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: That looks promising, thanks - I will try it on some text and see what it comes up with.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You're actually asking multiple questions, and there are algorithms like [the Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or the [longest common substring (LCS) problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), which is considered NP-hard. You can also find some other [edit-distance algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) if you look around with the right keywords.

Since you haven't explained what you're doing with the resulting outputs, it's hard to give you an idiomatic solution that will fit all your use cases, but these solutions (tested with Ruby 3.1.2, but should work with Ruby 2.7.6+) should at least get you started.

### Naive Matching of Array Sequences

Given the very basic example in your original first question, and making some assumptions such as:

1. You are looking for complete matches of *arr1*, not just the longest subsequence.
2. *arr1* will always be shorter than *arr2*.
3. The subsequence could match zero or more times.

then you can use the #size of *arr1* to create a sliding window over *arr2*, and then #select matches that contain the same value as *arr1*. Since arrays (unlike sets or set-like difference or union operations) are ordered, `[1, 2, 3] == [3, 2, 1] #=> false`, which means you'll only get matches when a sub-sequence of *arr2* is an exact match for a sub-sequence in *arr1* of the same length and with elements in the same ordinal positions.

Consider the following:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]

subseq = arr2.each_cons(arr1.size).select { _1 == arr1 }
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

The end result is an array-of-arrays, which will either be #empty? if no sub-sequences were found, or the matched sequences. You can then iterate over the matches, if any, or just do something with `subseq.pop` if you want to work with a single value.

You may have to validate the assumptions above, or pursue a different solution if you are looking for matching substrings of *arr1* with *arr2*, but while a bit naive the solution matches the inputs and outputs you provided.

### Matching Items by Index

This is a different problem, because you are no longer really looking at sub-sequences. Instead, you are comparing items at a given *index*. There are a couple of ways you might solve this quickly without resorting to complex algorithms, including #zip and #each_with_index. Consider the following examples.

#### Comparing by Index

The following naive solution assumes that:

1. Your arrays are both the same size.
2. You want to return any value of *arr2* that isn't isn't in the same index location as *arr1*.

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]

arr1.each_with_index do |elem, idx|
    arr2[idx] unless elem == arr2[idx]
end
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This will of course give bad results if the two arrays are of different sizes. In that case, you might need a smarter comparison such as:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]

(0...[arr1.size, arr2.size].max).map do |idx|
  arr1[idx] == arr2[idx] ? nil : arr2[idx]
end
#=> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

which will show elements from *arr2* that are different, even if there's no matching index in *arr1*.

#### When Arrays Aren't Unique

This solution return values that are different, and `nil` where they are the same so that you can see no word was changed at that index. For example:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 3, 2, 4]
arr2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]

arr1.each_with_index.
  map { _1 == arr2[_2] ? nil : arr2[_2] }
#=> [4, nil, nil, 1]
```

If you don't want `nil` then replace it with `_1` like so:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = [4, 3, 2, 1]

arr1.each_with_index.
  map { _1 == arr2[_2] ? nil : arr2[_2] }
#=> [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

#### Handling Unbalanced Arrays

You also have an edge case where your arrays may not be balanced. Another somewhat naive solution is to simply #zip the arrays, return values that don't match the sub-arrays or hashed key/value pairs, and then deal with the "overhang" of unbalanced items. For example:

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]

changed = arr1.zip(arr2).to_h.
  map { _1 == _2 ? nil : _2 }
  .append (arr1.size - arr2.size)
  .negative? ? arr2.last : arr1.last
#=> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

### Conclusion

All of these approaches basically rely on indexing rather than set-matching. They're also all pretty fast as they use built-in objects and methods rather than hand-crafted algorithms. They may not be a comprehensive replacement for specific LCS or edit-distance algorithms, but they all solve aspects of your stated problem with repeatable and predictable results so long as you meet the foundational assumptions.

If none of these fit your exact use case, they should at least get you started with devising your own after you identify whatever edge cases may apply. Failing that, a more complex solution may be needed, but these approaches have served me well for most of the use cases I've run across in real-world code. Your mileage may certainly vary.

Comment: @engineersmnky The first example probably does need to be reworked. I'll take a closer look later. You're right about the hashing; it was a convenience based on the provided samples, but comparing elements of each two-element sub-array would be safer.